# PHP - flock() automatic release in versions since 5.3.2

Tags: php, flock

As the Manual states

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.flock.php

```
On versions of PHP before 5.3.2, the lock is released also by fclose() (which is also called automatically when script finished).
```

As far as I understand the lock isn't released automatically since version 5.3.2. Is that correct?

Furtheron this leads to the question if the lock is released while the script execution has been aborted by the client (by HTTP request or CLI).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lock isn't released automatically since 5.3.2

If you terminate the script before unlocking. PHP won't unlock it. You then have to relay on the OS to do so.

In short: always unlock

Comment: **fartingsoundofareleasedballoon** So a stream wrapper applying its stream handle to a registry after locking and a shutdown handler to close all applied handles of that registry are the only way then. Any known reason why they removed the auto release?

Comment: Couldn't find a reason on Github or in the bug tracker. Just this report with a response saying that it was intensional: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=51771